# Restarting GNOME Shell by pressing using Alt+F2 is not working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, wayland

Two days ago I installed Ubuntu 22.04 and I was trying to restart GNOME Shell using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. The command prompt opened, but when I entered `r` and pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>, GNOME Shell does not restart.

The following message was coming as displayed on the image:

> **Restart is not available on Wayalnd**

[image: screenshot showing the error message]

What can I do now to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please enter this command:

```
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
```

If the above command outputs, `wayland`, your system is using Wayland, and as the error in the screenshot informs, restart is not available on a Wayland session. We have to disable Wayland and enable Xorg (X11) to be able to restart GNOME Shell.

To do this follow these steps:

1. Open the `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` file with `nano`:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
   ```
2. Uncomment this line.

   ```
   WaylandEnable=false
   ```
3. Reboot your system.

Voila! You can now press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, enter `r` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to restart GNOME Shell.

Also, running:

```
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
```

should now display `x11`.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

[a Gnome mailing list thread says that](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2015-March/msg01019.html):

runDialog: Disable restart command on wayland

> Clients can be expected to deal with the WM going away temporarily,
> but not the display server - so when running as wayland compositor, a
> restart is generally a fancy way of killing the user session, and
> there's little we can do about it except for preventing the user to
> shoot herself in the foot by throwing an error.

Comment: That means I cannot do anything to solve this?

Comment: Under Wayland, gnome-shell does not have a graceful way to restart and leave the applications open. If you must restart gnome-shell then you are probably better off saving all of your work and using the menu to log out. If that's not working for some reason, the command killall -HUP gnome-shell will get it done from the command runner (Alt+F2) or terminal.